# Streaming Audio: how to make IceCast with EZStream output in SIP format for MOH on SIP phones

Tags: sip, audio-streaming, rtp, telephony

I currently have Icecast running with EZ stream, outputting http music on hold streams. I have a need to convert this in a SIP format, so phones such as the SNOM 720 can play the feed on hold. Can this be done?